# Is there a way such that I can write this code more efficiently?

Tags: python, if-statement, coding-efficiency

Guys any idea how this code could be written to use more sophisticated and less lines?
Especially the body part where the instructions are being executed seem to be very redundant.

Thanks in advance.

```
 z = """Wählen Sie eine der folgenden vorgegebenen Operationen: (add/subtract/multiply/divide/end/history)
    """
    a = "Erste Zahl: "
    b = "Zweite Zahl: "
    ops = ["add","subtract","multiply","divide"]
    list = []
    answer = input(z)

    def add(x,y):
        return x+y
    def sub(x,y):
        return x-y
    def mult(x,y):
        return x*y
    def div(x,y):
        return x/y

    while answer in ops:
        if answer == "add":
            print("Resultat: ",add(int(input(a)),int(input(b))))
            list.append(answer)
            answer = input(z)
        elif answer == "subtract":
            print("Resultat: ",sub(int(input(a)),int(input(b))))
            list.append(answer)
            answer = input(z)
        elif answer == "multiply":
            print("Resultat: ",mult(int(input(a)),int(input(b))))
            list.append(answer)
            answer = input(z)
        elif answer == "divide":
            print("Resultat: ",div(int(input(a)),int(input(b))))
            list.append(answer)
            answer = input(z)

    if answer == "history":
        print(list)
        answer = input(z)

    elif answer == "end":
        print("Das Programm wird beendet.")

    else:
        print("""Geben Sie bitte eine gültige Eingabe ein.""")
        answer = input(z)
```

Best,
Gianluca

Comment: This is a common FAQ. Store the operands and the associated function for each in a `dict`.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a mapping between the operands and the functions. In C or C++ we would call that a function pointer, in C# we'd call it an Action or a lambda. Anyway, it looks like this and I have reused `ops` for that:

```
ops = {"add":add, "subtract":sub, "multiply":mult, "divide":div}
```

Next, you can replace the function call like `add(...)` by `ops[answer](...)`:

```
    if answer == "add":
        print("Resultat: ",ops[answer](int(input(a)),int(input(b))))
        list.append(answer)
        answer = input(z)
```

Good thing: this applies to all functions. Therefore, you can get rid of all the `if` and `elif` statements:

```
z = """Wählen Sie eine der folgenden vorgegebenen Operationen: (add/subtract/multiply/divide/end/history)
"""
a = "Erste Zahl: "
b = "Zweite Zahl: "

list = []
answer = input(z)


def add(x, y):
    return x + y


def sub(x, y):
    return x - y


def mult(x, y):
    return x * y


def div(x, y):
    return x / y


ops = {"add": add, "subtract": sub, "multiply": mult, "divide": div}

while answer in ops:
    print("Resultat: ", ops[answer](int(input(a)), int(input(b))))
    list.append(answer)
    answer = input(z)

if answer == "history":
    print(list)
    answer = input(z)

elif answer == "end":
    print("Das Programm wird beendet.")

else:
    print("""Geben Sie bitte eine gültige Eingabe ein.""")
    answer = input(z)
```

Also note that your program likely does not work as intended once you enter "history", but I'll leave that fix to you, because it's not related to the question.

From the comments:

> number inputs are not yet being stored into my list. How can I do this without having to recall the instruction input(a)/input(b) which interrupts the program?

You could store the numbers in variables and use them when adding text to the history:

```
while answer in ops:
    number1 = int(input(a))
    number2 = int(input(b))
    result = ops[answer](number1, number2)
    list.append(f"{number1} {answer} {number2} = {result}")
    print("Resultat: ", result)
    answer = input(z)
```

The output then is:

```
history
['3 add 4 = 7', '8 subtract 2 = 6']
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you!

Comment: Just have one more question regarding the history function that you mentioned:
I think you meant that my number inputs are not yet being stored into my list.
How can I do this without having to recall the instruction input(a)/input(b) which interrupts the program?

Comment: @gvncore: What I meant is: once you enter "history", it goes out of the `while` loop. You then print the history and ask for input again. But there's no code following that would handle any calculation. The program ends. Try it: "add", "history", "add" - program ends wihtout letting you enter 2 numbers

Comment: @gvncore: I've added an example on how to store the numbers as well

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
while answer in ops:
    if answer == "add":
        print("Resultat: ",add(int(input(a)),int(input(b))))
    elif answer == "subtract":
        print("Resultat: ",sub(int(input(a)),int(input(b))))
    elif answer == "multiply":
        print("Resultat: ",mult(int(input(a)),int(input(b))))
    elif answer == "divide":
        print("Resultat: ",div(int(input(a)),int(input(b))))

   list.append(answer)
   answer = input(z)
```

Comment: While shorter, you have changed the behavior: `list.append()` is now called in any case, even for "history" or "end". That was not the case in the original code.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Is that right?  `list.append ()` is under `while answer in ops`, so it wouldn't do that for 'history' or 'end'.

Comment: ok, granted. It would only be different if `ops` contained other values. My fault.